# VuePress : Custom Contents in Sidebar for Exery Single Page

Tags: vue.js, web, vuepress

I would like to have custom links and different sidebar for every single page I don't want my headings render as table of contents in sidebar I would like to have custom content like this.

```
Node JS
-Lecture 1 Introduction
--Sub Lecture

-Lecture 2 Basics
--Sub Lecture
---Nested Lecture
```

Where all the lectures are custom links. So how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### sidebar

- Type: `false | 'auto' | SidebarConfigArray | SidebarConfigObject`
- Default: `'auto'`
- Details:

  Configuration of sidebar.

  You can override this global option via sidebar frontmatter in your pages.

  Set to `false` to disable sidebar.

  If you set it to `'auto'`, the sidebar will be automatically generated from the page headers.

  To configure the sidebar items manually, you can set this option to a *sidebar array*, each item of which could be a `SidebarItem` object or a string:

  - A `SidebarItem` object should have a `text` field, could have an optional `link` field and an optional `children` field. The `children` field should be a *sidebar array*.
  - A string should be the path to the target page file. It will be converted to a `SidebarItem` object, whose `text` is the page title, `link` is the page route path, and `children` is automatically generated from the page headers.

  If you want to set different sidebar for different sub paths, you can set this option to a *sidebar object*:

  - The key should be the path prefix.
  - The value should be a *sidebar array*.
- In order to add custom links external as well as internal see this:

```js
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    // sidebar object
    // pages under different sub paths will use different sidebar
    sidebar: {
      '/guide/': [
        {
          text: 'Guide',
          children: ['/guide/README.md', '/guide/getting-started.md'],
        },
      ],
      '/reference/': [
        {
          text: 'Reference',
          children: ['/reference/cli.md', '/reference/config.md'],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

For more info see [Sidebar Config](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/default-theme/config.html#sidebar)